# OrientDB 3 really compatible with Spring Data?

Tags: spring-data, orientdb, tinkerpop3

According to OrientDb official docs in http://orientdb.com/docs/3.0.x/apis-and-drivers/
OrientDb Spring Data is the Official Spring Data Plugin for both Graph and Document APIs
But Graph API 2.6 are deprecated (http://orientdb.com/docs/3.0.x/java/Java-API.html ) and substituted by TinkerPop 3.0 Graph API. 
Since OrientDb Spring Data reports: "Latest commit 5ad39de on 25 Mar 2016", how is it possible that is this yet compatible with the new TinkerPop 3.0 Graph API ?